# Push from TableView to another TableView gets Black Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I select a row from a TableView which gets informations from a Webservice. Everything is loaded: A search, then we get results and then choose one.
But after choosing one, I can set the data to the other view and make another web service to Work.. I'm okay with that.
The problem is to show the new table containing the results of the new web service..

I get this after choosing a row from the last table View:

```
2012-04-30 13:54:29.687 +%¨*%¨%¨*[6759:f803] JSON(
    "Name Gerald",
    "",
    4,
    FR,
    ""
)
```

I made this with this:

```
    NSString *nom = [olo objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *hd = [olo objectForKey:@"24_7"];
    NSString *passenger = [olo objectForKey:@"passengers"];
    NSString *country = [olo objectForKey:@"country"];
    NSString *special = [olo objectForKey:@"special_trip"];


    _jsonOlo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nom, hd, passenger, country, special, nil];
```

But when I set the table I get a black screen :

1st:

http://tinypic.com/r/2uzpc20/6

2:

http://tinypic.com/r/287qeeq/6

I have the same code as the last tableView which sends to the results but I get Black screen.

Comment: How are you loading data in your second tableview. Please furnish some code.

Comment: There could be several possible reasons
1. Check whether you have properly assigned your databsource and delegate to tableview.
2. Whether you could have missed to set outlet of tableview to file owner.
3. Your second table view cellforrowatindexpath has some errors.

Comment: data source and delegate is self as last tableView.

Comment: Please do the same for this table view also.

Comment: I set up the table by code... And it draws it and insert the information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two tableviews are different and you are not simply changing the datasource of the same table then your view might be loading before you have got all the data from web service .I don't know, which framework you are using for json parsing but there should be a delegate which signifies the end of getting results from web service . Parse the data there and then send it to the tableview in **viewDiDLoad** method.

Comment: I do that in view did load... Then in request finish method i get the JSON Parser... And send it to an array. I'm not really sure about the two tableView, maybe is that the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have connected the tableview properly in your XIB or you might not have added subview to main view or u must have allocated it when the webservice has finished retrieving data but u might have touched it before.

You can do one thing: make the cell selection disable till u are ready with all the data.